# Firefox Questions

Tags: firefox

Are there any optimized builds and/or processor specific builds of Firefox, like Swiftfox: 
http://getswiftfox.com/ for Ubuntu ? I've been tweaking config like it's my job, just like I did on that other os I just came over from, but still I want more performance.

Is there any way to preload Firefox on Ubuntu ? I know about the system preloader that's available but there seems to be contention among the information I've read; some say use it, some say don't ........

The closest app to speedy fox I can find is the Vacuum Places extension, which I haven't used yet: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vacuum-places-improved/?src=api

Thanks in advance for your replies, I look forward to your input.

Comment: You can certainly compile firefox yourself, great thing about open source, and optimize for your hardware. You can try all the tweaks as you suggest. You might even see some performance boosts if you benchmark firefox, but, honestly, you are highly unlikely to notice much of a perfomance boots.

Comment: compiling is way beyond my scope, I'm new to linux. I'm using the smart referer extension in firefox and earlier I changed the pref from domain I'm going to as referer to send nothing as a referer, looking like a direct hit. I swear my browser is faster now. Wasn't expecting or more honestly didn't know what to expect but it seems to have helped.

Comment: No time like the present to learn =) see http://funroll-loops.info/  Honestly compiling is not difficult ./configure; make; sudo make install. You just need to track down the dependencies. see the gcc flags for your CPU to optimize for your arch. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/gcc/i386-and-x86-64-Options.html

Comment: whoa !!! ...... I'm just trying to get scripts done correctly, take ownership of files so I can delete, etc.

Comment: Well, welcime to Linux. In general when you ask or use the words "optimized builds and/or processor specific builds" in the Linux community you are implying that you wish to "take ownership", jump in, and start compiling (rather then trust or accept that the Ubuntu maintainers / packagers / developers have already optimzed the code).

Answer (score 1):

Palemoon is a Firefox fork (based on [Firefox ESR](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/) specifically) that is up to date and has all security patches.

**From the site**: Pale Moon is an Open Source, Firefox-based web browser available for Microsoft Windows and Linux, focusing on efficiency and ease of use. Make sure to get the most out of your browser!

http://www.palemoon.org/

Comment: ok thanks didn't realize there was palemoon for linux. I thought it was doggy on windows, but then again that's why I'm here. Full install, no vmware for me ;-)

Comment: anyone using palemoon on linux ? is it any faster than standard firefox ?

Comment: Palemoon it IS !!!!!! Thanks again for the suggestion. I wasn't considering Palemoon as an option because it was really doggy on windows for me but it's robust on Xubuntu 14.04, easily 2x faster all around than standard Firefox. Highly recommend.

Answer (score -1):

There is Swift fox for Ubuntu.

Add the repository to /etc/apt/sources.list 
deb http://getswiftfox.com/builds/debian unstable non-free
sudo apt-get update && apt-get install swiftfox-prescott

Not sure if it's active.